# Javascript Canvas - Get simple font properties

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

I set the font of a html5 canvas:

```
context.font = "italic bold 24px Verdana";
```

Is there a way to retrieve these properties **individually** like in css?

What I want is something like this:

context.fontStyle, context.fontWeight, context.fontSize, context.fontFamily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

You can use this library to set various font properties to render text on canvas.

http://txtjs.com/

## Original post

Font properties on the canvas context does not exist (at least not yet).

Instead, you can create string variables and then concatenate them together.

```
var fontStyle = "italic";
var fontWeight = "bold";
var fontSize = "24px";
var fontFamily = "Verdana";
var b = " ";

context.font = fontStyle + b + fontWeight + b + fontSize + b + fontFamily;
```

This example shows how you can use object variables:

```
var myFont = {
    style: "italic",
    weight: "bold",
    size: "24px",
    family: "Verdana"
}

var b = " ";

function canvasFont(font) {
    context.font = font.style + b + font.weight + b + font.size + b + font.family;
}

myFont.size = "20px";
canvasFont(myFont);
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xPBcC/1/).

Comment: It's right, i can set the properties this way. But my problem is, that I want to write a function that sets e.g. only the FontSize to 20px, not knowing which fontFamily and fontStyle are currently on the context.

Comment: I wanted to extend the canvas context with some useful functions like context.drawText(x, y, text, options). So the user could e.g. set context.font="10px Arial" somewhere at the beginning of his script. And then just use context.drawText(10, 10, "text", {fontSize: "12px"}). So that he doesn't need to specify the fontFamily each time he is drawing some text.

Comment: Sorry, this canvas font thing got me confused. Your idea is right. Thanks!